# Why is version not being set by Cmake?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to set up **CMAKE** as a build system, so am quite new to it. Have done quite a bit of extensive research before posting this question but i couldn't find an answer. I have been looking for the past day and some of the links are [here](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/basics.html), [and here](https://gist.github.com/mbinna/c61dbb39bca0e4fb7d1f73b0d66a4fd1), and [in the official documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/project.html?highlight=project) but i do not understand what i am doing wrong.

Question: I am trying to build a dynamic library with cmake but the version is not being set.

This is my folder structure, generated with the "**tree**" command. (i have taken out stuff from the build directory so it is easily readable)

```
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── test_utility.cpp
└── test_utility.h
```

This is my **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(TestLib
        VERSION 0.1
        DESCRIPTION "Testing the library target utility in Cmake"
        LANGUAGES CXX)

add_library (test_utility SHARED test_utility.cpp test_utility.h)
```

Then i go to the build directory and run **cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles"** and **cmake --build .** . Everything finishes nicely except for one thing:
The resultof this is **libtest_utility.so** whereas i would have wanted **libtest_utility.so.0.1** and then i would do the symlink myself.

I know about the workarround solution from [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-September/051904.html) that tells to use **VERSION_MAJOR** 0 and **VERSION_MINOR** 1 but i thought that the Version attribute in project should take care of it.

**Question:** Why isn'tt the version being set

Comment: You need to set [VERSION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/VERSION.html) property for the **target**, this is what the [last reference](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-September/051904.html) talking about. The *project*'s version is unrelated to the *library*'s version.

Comment: Thank you, so what purpose does the project version serve? Also [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/project.html?highlight=project#command:project) it says that the project command should store those variables by itself from the **VERSION** attribute or maybe i am missunderstanding

Comment: `project()` command sets `PROJECT_VERSION_*` *variables*, but these variables do **not affect** on creating soversion files. As I said in my previous comment, it is setting *VERSION* **property** which affects on creation soversion files. As for project's VERSION parameter, it is mostly informative. For example, you may embed this version into some of your files.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answers my question but i do not have the right to close it as answered. I will flag this to a moderator.

Comment: **Comments** are not **answers**, so the cannot be "accepted". I will write my answer later.

Comment: @eucristian `PROJECT_VERSION` sets the version of the entire project. One place where this is useful is defining a use requirement. For example, calling `find_package(<package> 2.1)` from another project checks that `PROJECT_VERSION` of your project is at least 2.1.

Comment: this is another really usefull answer. Thank you as well!

Answer (score 1):

Project's version, which is set by the *VERSION* parameter of the `project()`, denotes only version of the project, not the version of the libraries it produces.

For set version of the library, you need to set *VERSION* **property** of the library **target**:

```
set_target_properties(test_utility PROPERTIES VERSION "0.1")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the version of the project is set, this value can be reused for the built targets. Just read the project version instead of value duplication

Set the version of the project:

```
project(TestLib
    VERSION 0.1
    DESCRIPTION "Testing the library target utility in Cmake"
    LANGUAGES CXX)
```

Use the value of `PROJECT_VERSION`

```
add_library (test_utility SHARED test_utility.cpp test_utility.h)
set_target_property(test_utility PROPERTIES VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
```